# How do one calculate the fb_videomode parameters in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, framebuffer, lcd

I would like to write a driver to http://www.trulydisplays.com/tft/specs/3.5in%20480x800%20TFT480800-25-E%20Spec.pdf  How do I calculate all the following params:

```
struct fb_videomode {
    const char *name;   /* optional */
    u32 refresh;        /* optional */
    u32 xres;
    u32 yres;
    u32 pixclock;
    u32 left_margin;
    u32 right_margin;
    u32 upper_margin;
    u32 lower_margin;
    u32 hsync_len;
    u32 vsync_len;
    u32 sync;
    u32 vmode;
    u32 flag;
};
```

Comment: I found this document that might be of help                           https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt         Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope those fields mentioned are available in the [**EDID**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) of the display device.